# Segemented SVG Outlined Circle

Tags: html, css, svg, geometry

Thanks in advance for your help!

I am trying to build an SVG circle which has no fill only an outline and is split into 3 segments.

I have managed to find a thread that shows me how to split a circle into 4 segments (see snippet) but I am very new to SVG's so I don't really know what is going on and how to get this to 3 segments and only the outline.

I have attached a screenshot showing the outcome of the circle. I don't want any visible sign of the segments but I want to be able to use each segment separately. (Basically I am going to have a page where the circle completes itself as you scroll down the page.)

[image: Segemnted Circle]

```html
        <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
          <g transform="translate(100,100)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2">
            <path d="M0 0-70 70A99 99 0 0 1-70-70Z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M0 0-70-70A99 99 0 0 1 70-70Z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M0 0 70-70A99 99 0 0 1 70 70Z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M0 0 70 70A99 99 0 0 1-70 70Z" fill="none"/>
          </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: It depends what you mean by "outline".  I suspect you mean that you want the circle arcs to be drawn as a thick line.  What SVG calls a "stroke".  Is that right?  The alternative would be where the segment shape is outlines and filled with colour. In otherwords two arcs of different radii joined by straight lines at their ends. Then filled with the blue/green colour.

Comment: If you want to learn how paths work. You can read about them in the [Paths section of the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#paths-PathData).  It's not that complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all Math, let a native Web Component `<svg-segments>` do the work.
The important part in the *created* SVG `<path>` are the `pathLength` and `stroke-dasharray` values

**All** you specify, is a **string** of colors defining how many and what color segments are drawn.
A none color will create an empty segment:

`<svg-segments parts="red,,blue"></svg-segments>`

[image]

In the SO snippet below; click the circles to add more segments

```html
<div style="display:grid;grid:1fr/repeat(5,1fr);gap:10px;background:grey">
  <svg-segments parts="red,green,blue"></svg-segments>
  <svg-segments parts="red,,blue"></svg-segments>
  <svg-segments parts=",,red"></svg-segments>
  <svg-segments parts="red,green,blue,purple" width="5"></svg-segments>
  <svg-segments parts="red,,,green,,blue,,red,red" width="50"></svg-segments>
</div>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-segments", class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["parts", "size"]; // svg is redrawn at *every* attribute update!
    }
    attributeChangedCallback() {
      this.parts = this.getAttribute("parts").split(",");
      let vb = 200; // viewPort size; might need to tweak this
      let width = this.getAttribute("width") || 25; // stroke-width
      let a = vb / 2 - width/2; // calculate circle arcs
      let b = vb - width;
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox='0 0 ${vb} ${vb}'>` +
        this.parts.map((col, idx) => {
          if (col)
            return `<path d='M${width/2},${vb/2}a${a},${a} 0 1,0 ${b},0a${a},${a} 0 1,0 -${b},0' 
            fill='none' stroke-width='${width}' pathLength='${this.parts.length}'
            stroke='${col}' stroke-dashoffset='${idx}'
            stroke-dasharray='1 ${this.parts.length-1}'/>`;
          else return ``;
        }) + `</svg>`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {// for StackOverflow Snippet demo purpose only
      this.onclick = (evt) => { 
        let moreparts = this.parts.join(",") + ",red";
        this.setAttribute("parts", moreparts);
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

SVG has some quirks calculating path-arcs, you may need to tweak the viewPort dimensions to a higher dimension when you see artifacts (red):

[image]

Or re-factor to use `<circle>`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to calculate the starting and the ending point of every arc. Since you want 3 arcs the angle used is 1/3 of a circle i.e 2*Math.PI/3.

Please read the comments in the code.

```js
//the circle's radius
let r = 70;
//points used for the start and end of every arc
let points =[];
//the paths
let ps = document.querySelectorAll("path");

//calculating the points used for the start and end of every arc
for(let angle = -Math.PI/2; angle < 2*Math.PI; angle += 2*Math.PI/3 ){
  let point = {}
  point.x = r * Math.cos(angle);
  point.y = r * Math.sin(angle);
  points.push(point)
}

//defining the valueof the d attribute of every path as an arc with the given radius, starting at the previous point and ending at the actual point
for(let i = 0,l=points.length; i<l-1; i++){
  let point = points[i+1];
  let prev = points[i]
  let d = `M${prev.x},${prev.y} A${r},${r},0,0,1,${point.x},${point.y}`
  //setting the d attribute
  ps[i].setAttribute("d",d);
}
```

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" width="300" fill="none" stroke-width="20">
  <path stroke="gold"/>
  <path stroke="skyBlue"/>
  <path stroke="tomato"/>
</svg>
```